# How to change the Edit mode in stackedit.io to right to left only at certain rows?

Tags: markdown, stackedit

I am using the markdown editor StackEdit. I want my article to be written in 2 different modes:
Certain rows to be written from right-to-left and some others to be left-to-right.
Is there such a possible way to do it? I see in the settings menu that I can change the direction but only for the whole document.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible but requires quite a bit of programming. StackEdit accepts custom extensions where you can add extra functionality to it.

See [**UserCustom extensions · benweet/stackedit Wiki**](https://github.com/benweet/stackedit/wiki/UserCustom-extensions)

Custom scripts are added at the very end of Settings » Extensions:

[image: StackEdit custom extensions location]